# moment js extract year from string

Tags: javascript, date, momentjs

I'm new to moment.js and I can't really understand the documentation. I'd like to manipulate some dates in string format.

I have my date as string from json feed and looks like:

```
var year = item.date
// it returns a string like "25/04/2012"
```

How do I extract the year from it using moment.js ?

Answer (score 69, accepted):

You can use

```
moment("25/04/2012","DD/MM/YYYY").format("YYYY")
or    
moment("25/04/2012","DD/MM/YYYY").year()
```

in your example:

```
moment(item.date,"DD/MM/YYYY").year()
```

Answer (score 2):

Or you can convert the string to date then extract the year:

```
var date = new Date(dateString);
if (!isNaN(date)) {
    return date.getFullYear();
}
```

Comment: Just the name of the  variable is "date" not "d"